# How can I update my state in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to uptade my state when I click the submit button.
This is my react code:

```
const [editAreaName, setEditAreaName] = useState("");

function areaNameUpdateSubmit(e, areaId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.updateArea(areaId,editAreaName);
  }

  {props.area.map((mekan) => (
                <Tab
                  key={mekan.areaId}
                  eventKey={mekan.areaId}
                  title={mekan.areaName}
                >
                  
                   <form
                    className="alert alert-primary m-5"
                    onSubmit={(e) => areaNameUpdateSubmit(e, mekan.areaId)}
                  >
                    <h1>mekan adı:{mekan.areaName}</h1>
                    <input
                      onChange={(e) => setEditAreaName(e.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                    <button type="submit" className="alert alert-danger">
                      Change area name
                    </button>
                  </form>
))}
```

this is my action.js file. I want to send two payload variables.

```
export const updateArea = (id, newAreaName) => {
  return { type: UPDATE_AREA, payload: { id, newAreaName } };
};
```

This is my state type:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  area: [
    { areaId: 0, areaName: "Inside" },
    { areaId: 1, areaName: "Garden" },
  ],
  table: [
    { tableId: 0, areaId: 0, tableName: "TABLE 1" },
    { tableId: 1, areaId: 1, tableName: "TABLE 2" },
    { tableId: 2, areaId: 1, tableName: "TABLE 3" },
    { tableId: 3, areaId: 1, tableName: "TABLE 4" },
    { tableId: 4, areaId: 4, tableName: "TABLE 5" },
  ],
};
```

And this is my reducer. There is a loop the area state and if areaId and action.id equal then I want to change my this area object.

```
  case "UPDATE_AREA":
      return {
        area: state.area.map((area) => {
          if (area.areaId === action.id) {
            return {
              ...area,
              areaName: action.newAreaName,
            };
          }
          return area;
        }),
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access different action properties in reducer from those that you pass in your action creator.

In your reducer change `area.areaId` to `area.payload.areaId` and `action.newAreaName` to `action.payload.newAreaName`.

Answer (score 0):

This code probably needs to use `action.payload.id`

```
case "UPDATE_AREA":
  return {
    ...state,
    area: state.area.map((area) => {
      if (area.areaId === action.payload.id) {
        return {
          ...area,
          areaName: action.payload.newAreaName,
        };
      }
      return area;
    }),
  };
```